# delphi how to insert line break (border below) in word ole automation

Tags: delphi, ms-word, ole

Inside Word app, when I type `---` and press ENTER, Word inserts a horizontal line `_____` (that is a border only below line).

I need to insert the same horizontal line, but using delphi ole automation.
Anyone know how?
I tried:

```
  Word := CreateOleObject('Word.Application');
  Word.Visible := False;
  Doc:=Word.Documents.Add;
  Selection:=Word.Selection;
  Range:= Word.Selection.Range;
  Table:= Word.ActiveDocument.Tables;
  View:= Word.ActiveWindow.View;
  (...)
  Word.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView := 10;
  Selection.TypeText(Text :='---'#13#10); <--- No sucess!
```

Any Help will be welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I have found the reason for the difference in behaviour you describe, and a couple of ways to get a similar effect via automation as you get by manual typing.

When you type something by hand, Word's AutoCorrect/AutoFormat facility is "listening" to what you type and, when it recognises something that it has been programmed to act upon, like three hyphens in a row, it intervenes and takes the appropriate AutoCorrect/AutoFormat action.

However, in an automation call, if you insert text (via TypeText) that would have been auto-formatted if typed manually, the AutoFormating doesn't occur automatically - I imagine this may be because TypeText() bypasses Word's code which processes keyboard input.  Word macros that call TypeText() behave this way too.  But you ***can*** invoke it in your automation code, like this:

```
  MSWord.Selection.TypeText('Some text');
  MSWord.Selection.TypeText(#13#10);

  MSWord.Selection.TypeText('---');
  MSWord.Selection.Range.AutoFormat;
```

I haven't thoroughly tested the above on other AutoFormat entries, I would expect it to work with them, so I suppose it might have the "advantage" over other methods that you don't need to know how thw formatting actually gets done :-).

Alternatively, you can apply the effect manually, as shown in the other answer, or by the code I posted in my initial attempt to answer your q, namely

```
  Word.Selection.TypeText('Some text');
  Word.Selection.TypeText(#13#10);
  Word.Selection.InlineShapes.AddHorizontalLineStandard;
  Word.Selection.TypeText('More text');
```

Hopefully between these three possibilities, you'll be able to get the effect you're after.

Comment: Excellent finding! I tested with `'---'`, `'==='`, `'***'` and many others, and many if not most of the autocorrection / autoformat rules work (if enabled in the users setup!). Some did not, e.g. '(e)' should give the euro sign in my setup, but doesn't. It does however when typing on the keyboard.

Comment: Thanks, @Tom.  I'm still playing with it but have run into some wrinkles myself with the AutoCorrect expansions (in the list below the "Replace text as you type" checkbox on the AutoCorrect tab) - seems that as long as the Word GUI gets control back immediately after my Selection.Autoformat *and* I then press the space bar manually, the expanded text gets substituted for the short code.  BUT I haven't yet found anything I can do in the automation code that can take the place of pressing the space-bar and get the autotext expanded.  I might start a q of my own about that ...

Comment: MartynA, I think we have already answered this question, so it might be a good idea to open a new one specifically for other issues regarding AutoCorrect / AutoFormat. Or we could have a more free form chat at Emb OleAutomation forum.

Answer (score 2):

The following adds a border below (wdBorderBottom).

```
const
  wdBorderBottom = -3;
  wdLineStyleSingle = 1;
  wdLineWidth075pt = 6;
  wdColorBlack = 0;

var
  Border: OleVariant;

begin
  // ...
  Border := Word.Selection.Borders[wdBorderBottom];
  Border.LineStyle := wdLineStyleSingle;
  Border.LineWidth := wdLineWidth075pt;
  Border.Color := wdColorBlack;
  // ...
end;
```

Comment: Thanks @TomBrunberg: That looks a bit more like what the OP may be after.

Comment: @MartynA Your is easier to use :)

Comment: Thank you guys, every thing works perfect! I am learning work with ole automation and msword/excel, but no documentation about. I am doing using examples by google.com. Now I need to create tables, but it´s another question that I need to search before.